# How do I uninstall Total Copy?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, context-menu

I installed Total Copy on a machine a while back
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Total-Copy.shtml

I want to get rid of it.

When I right click dragging a folder into another folder, I get a context menu apppear offering me to copy with total copy.  I don't want that option to appear.

I don't see Total Copy in add/remove programs, and I can't see its EXE, i'm not sure if it uses one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitoring the installation file, with Process Monitor, shows similar to saving it to another directory.

The default is it looks like the only files it installs, it installs to `c:\windows` specifying another directory seems to give an error.  But either way, you see these files..

```
46,080 COPYFSTQ.EXE
94,636 dropcpyr.dll
 8,134 irunin.bmp
 9,694 irunin.dat
17,922 irunin.ini
15,938 irunin.lng
 3,677 tc12.reg
   158 tcrunreg.bat
```

so dir /s /b those.

I deleted them and restarted.

I can't see what registry entries it wrote, but now when I right click drag one folder into another, it no longer says "total copy here".

I had this in xp. i'm not sure that it manages to affect the context menu in windows 7. so it's perhaps no issue in windows 7.

i'd add, there's nothing in add/remove programs, nothing in the start menu, and there seems to be no exe that if run, starts the program. for example the only exe I see it placing is copyfstq.exe and running that I don't even see it in process manager so it might just close immediately. It's a tiny program, it looks like deleting its files might've been what got it out of the context menu cos I didn't do anything else to get it out.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know where you have installed it? Usually there is a an uninstall program in that folder. 
Microsoft recommends different ways.

> **Run the Uninstall Program Included in the Uninstall Folder**
>   Some programs create a folder under the Winnt folder that contains a "$" character at the start and end of the folder name. This folder may contain an uninstall program that you can run to remove the program you previously installed on your computer. Note that these folders are usually hidden, and that you may need to configure Windows Explorer to view hidden files and folders. To do so, right-click Start, click Explore, click Options on the View menu, and then click Show all files.

You could check out other solutions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247515).

Comment: I even included a link to the program so it shouldn't have been hard for you to test your solution or your thoughts and see that they don't apply